# Distribute Sql Server database alongside jar file

Tags: sql, jar, distribution

How can i bind Sql Server database with jar file for distribution.I am using JDBC-ODBC driver for connectivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is your application distributed? ear file? war file? jar file? zip file? jaws file?

In iether case I would advise against using the jdbc-odbc bridge, as this requires odbc configuration to be defined on the machine where your application will finally run.

I've successfully used the [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) driver against SQL server in the past.

This is a pure java type-4 jdbc driver, suggest that you familiarise yourself with the jdbc driver types 1 - 4,
see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver.

Comment: It's distributed as jar.Now i am using jTDS.I still have one doubt,how to copy my SQL Server databse to the detination machine alongside jar.

Comment: How to copy my SQL Server database and ntlmauth.dll file from jTDS  to \Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin folder of the destination machine ,without bothering the user,so the user just needs to click on the jar file to run the application.

Comment: Now i have another error,project was working when it was run in netbeans IDE but when i converted it as jar file it's not accessing database and i am getting null pointer exception.